# How do I create a scoring algorithm in R for a data set of a test?

Tags: r

I have a data set with a student name and their answers to an test on an excel sheet. I also have a key. How do I compare the key with the students' answers to output a score for each student?

Comment: We need more details to be able to help you here. The code you would use is entirely dependent on the specific structure of your data, which you haven't shown us. Also, you say the data is in an Excel spreadsheet. Have you imported it to R?

Answer (score 0):

Let's say there are four questions in the test and the student's answer and key answer are  :

```
student_answer<-c('a','b','b','d')

true_answer<-c('b','c','b','d')
```

then two questions were correctly answered:

```
sum(student_answer == true_answer)
```

[1] 2